# Wrong Open Graph image is shown (og:image) using yoast

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, open-graph

I am using Yoast plugin and have set the Open graph metadata, but the thumbnail image is wrong.
I have set the same image in these places:

```
Page editor > Social > Facebook image
```

```
SEO > Search appearance > General > Organization logo
```

```
SEO > Social > Facebook > default image
```

1. The tag `og:image` is the correct image in the page source.
2. I have checked the image with [facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it shows the right image.
3. I have refreshed google search console data. 
   But it is wrong both in every link I add somewhere, and in the SEO tab of wordpress page editor.

Does anybody know how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Dado, you'll have to check the Yoast support forums or open a ticket with them directly - third party plugins are off topic.  (I have had problems with the Facebook Debug Tool showing cached images before.)

Comment: OK @TonyDjukic, thank you! Hope it helps.